# How to dynamically set phantomJS command line options on Heroku

Tags: heroku, phantomjs

I have a phantomjs app running on heroku. I need to be able to set several commands which are normally accessed by the command line (https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference), preferably at runtime, but if necessary once a day.

I want to set the heroku procfile to:

```
phantomjs --config=/path/to/config.json somescript.js
```

where the config.json looks like

```
{
/* Same as: --ignore-ssl-errors=true */
"ignoreSslErrors": true,

/* Same as: --max-disk-cache-size=1000 */
"maxDiskCacheSize": 1000,

/* Same as: --output-encoding=utf8 */
"outputEncoding": "utf8"

/* etc. */
}
```

My thought is I would like to upload a json object to the heroku ephemeral filesystem before running my phantomjs app. I'm hoping when it runs it will use the updated config file. Does this seem reasonable? Has anyone tried something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set a variable through

```
heroku config:set NAME=VALUE
```

which is read at runtime, so you could change it whenever you need to.

You could also update config variables via their API: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#config-var, if you have the need to change them more often.

Comment: Alberto, I wasn't aware of this approach. I'll read up on it . Thank you. - Bill